# How to package a DLL to run for all users

Tags: c++, excel, dll, com, add-in

I have a C++ COM DLL created using Visual Studio 2010 Pro. I am trying to package a DLL for use in Excel. However, when I try to compile the DLL when I am not running in administrator mode I get an error stating that I need elevated privileges. Which I assumed was fine. I have then packaged the DLL using a Setup and Deploy project where I install and register the DLL to a specific path. This works well and good until the user tries to run the DLL.

If running it regularly then nothing will happen. Only when running in Administrator mode will the actual functions and everything work well. My question is if there is an easy way to allow for the installer to add what it needs to run for all machines or is it because I compiled the addin as an Administrator I need to somehow compile as a regular user for this to work? If the latter needs to be done how would I go about it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Determining Which DLLs to Redistribute : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kche8ah.aspx

Deployment Examples : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235285.aspx

Comment: I've been following the examples and I have the proper DLL. However I am still not able to run the plugin outside of administrator mode.